# Did I somehow accidentally remove the comments on my question?

Tags: support, status-completed, deleted-comments

I had four user comments to my post [Strange difference in cmd/bash/awk escape character requirement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61490699/strange-difference-in-cmd-bash-awk-escape-character-requirement), but now there are none. Did I do that somehow, or were they removed by the moderator? Is there a way for me to find out why?

Comment: What was the nature of the comments?

Comment: Comments are temporary. If you feel that comments contained important information that you did not edited into the question - you may want to flag your for moderator attention explaining that...

Comment: Well, two of them by the user @Mofi had helpful suggestions on how I could go about using Process Monitor to "debug" the issue, but I'm thinking none of them were considered "answers"...?

Comment: Do I need to mark all comments that should not be removed, even if they provide valid answers? Is it an automated process, or are they removed by a moderator? Are answers handled differently, or do they also need to be marked in order to be kept?

Comment: @hjartstrom: Generally, if a comment on your question turns out to provide the answer, it's a good idea to let the person know they should go ahead and post it as one. Failing that you could post your own answer, giving them credit.

Answer (score 8):

The participants deleted their own comments. It is not clear why.

Unfortunately, moderators cannot normally undelete comments that were self-deleted unless the owner has mod privileges, so I cannot restore the comments for you.